# Is there a good .Net component for drag/drop/resize drawing in 2D with connections (like Visio)?

Tags: .net, winforms, drawing, 2d

Is there a good .Net component for drag/drop/resize drawing in 2D with connections (like Visio) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly a component, but Netron is a good choice and is kept alive as a free version [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/netron-reloaded/). There's also more information and a newer version from the original developer [here](http://www.orbifold.net/default/?page_id=1272).